# Problemas com campo data no spring

Tags: java, jsp, spring, calendar

não estou conseguindorecuperar um campo data da minha jsp.

O campoestá assim:

```html
<label for="txtDataEvento">Data do Evento</label> 
   <input type="text" name="data" class="form-control" id="txtDataEvento" value="${evento.data}" />
```

O tipo do meu campo data no VO é Calendar e já coloquei a anotção que foi sugerida em alguns foruns.

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Calendar data;
```

Mesmo assim ainda continuo recebendo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Field error in object 'evento' on field 'data': rejected value
>   [20/06/2015]; codes
>   [typeMismatch.evento.data,typeMismatch.data,typeMismatch.java.util.Calendar,typeMismatch];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:

Alguém poderia ajudar?

Comment: Qual versão do Spring você está usando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brunão, provavelmente você vai precisar criar um *[PropertyEditor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyEditor.html?is-external=true)*

**Como o Spring faz para fazer o Bind do request parameter para uma Data/Field?**

O que acontece é que o Spring não sabe como converter esta String que é mostrada na tela - ***dd/MM/yyyy*** diretamente para uma Instancia de Calendar

Para Spring 3.X

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Calendar.class, new PropertyEditorSupport() {
        @Override
        public void setAsText(String value) {
            try {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(value));
                setValue(cal);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                setValue(null);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String getAsText() {
            if (getValue() == null) {
                return "";
            }
            return new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(((Calendar) getValue()).getTime());
        }
    });
}
```

Se puder dá uma olhada também nesta documentação de referência:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-ann-initbinder

Vai  matar seu problema.

Comment: Valew Filipe....funcionou uma beleza!!!!!!! Muito obrigado...